# Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, todomvc

I am following Ember's TodoMVC tutorial and I am stuck. Basically, I defined 2 controllers. This is todos.js

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions:{
        createTodo: function(){
            var title = this.get("newTitle");

            if(!title){
                return false;
            }
            if(!title.trim()){
                return;
            }

            var todo = this.store.createRecord("todo", {
                title: title,
                isCompleted: false
            });

            // Clear text field
            this.set('newTitle', '');

            todo.save();
        }
    }
})
```

This is todo.js

```
import Ember from "ember"

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isCompleted: function(key, value){
        var model = this.get("model");

        if(value === undefined){
            return model.get("isCompleted");
        } else {
            model.set('isCompleted', value);
            model.save();
            return value;
        }
    }.property('model','model.isCompleted')
});
```

Here is routes/todos.js

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find("todo");
    }
});
```

Finally, also defined todos.hbs

```
<ul id="todo-list">
    {{#each todo in model itemController="todo"}}
        <li {{bind-attr class="todo.isCompleted:completed"}}>
            {{input 
            type="checkbox"
            class="toggle"
            checked=todo.isCompleted
            }}
            <label>{{todo.title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Everything looks good, but I am getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must
>   be an Array. You passed todomvc-embercli@controller:array:, but it
>   should have been an ArrayController

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post your `todos` route as well?

Comment: todos.js route posted :)

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Do you by chance have [prototype extensions disabled](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/)?

Comment: I just  added the following: 

EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: true
      }
    }

into config/environment.js. Same result. Here is the complete environment.js file: https://code.stypi.com/w2v2pkm5

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you trying changing your controller so it extends from just `Controller` instead of `ArrayController`? Also, would you mind posting the version of Ember you're using as well?

Comment: Extended from Controller. Same thing. About library versions, this is what I see in the console: 

Ember: 1.9.1, 
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.17, 
Handlebars : 2.0.0, 
jQuery     : 1.11.3

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm a little lost at this point. :/ It seems like an Ember quirk/bug, but not one that I've seen before. Can you try removing the `itemController` from your loop?

Comment: If removed, it works again :)

Comment: There's definitely something fishy with Ember then. I remember a certain scenario where item controllers don't work. I'll try to dig it and up and get back to you with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

As per [turboMaCk's comment](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11259#issuecomment-110297838), removing ember-disable-proxy-controllers from package.json seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[This issue was just reported yesterday](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11259) on the Ember GitHub page. It seems to be a bug with Ember and I don't know of a workaround. However, it does mention that you can use components instead of a array and item controllers (which is the preferred method anyway). Maybe try looking at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97) that was posted in the issue.

I'll come back and update this answer if a workaround/fix is found. For now, I would say try to avoid array controllers (even though it's in the tutorial). :/

Comment: Well, it's good to know that once in a while it's the framework's fault and not yours :)